# Sunspot Solr environment difficult

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm using the amazing sunspot gem(github.com/outoftime/sunspot) on a rails application but I'm having such a huge problem. I confess that I still don't know how to configure it correctly according to my environment, but everything is set up and running well on my local and stage servers.

Well, to sum up, my problem is that in production I have a model that is currently updated - every list that envolves this model, an attribute is incremented. And the main problem is that when I try to perform a complex search on this model(not contextual) the `Connection Refused` error appears to me but solr is running up and performing all other searches.

My `solrconfig.xml` is just like sunspot installation, I didn't change anything. Is the autoCommit section the solution for this, or is nothing to do with it ?

Sorry for the last update, I wasn't made a newbie mistake, the result of "ps aux | grep java" on the server:

ubuntu    4039  0.0  1.8 2278060 144084 ?      Ssl  Jan21   8:10 java -Djetty.port=8983 -Dsolr.data.dir=/home/ubuntu/mallguide/mallguide-rails/solr/data/production -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/ubuntu/mallguide/mallguide-rails/solr -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/logging.properties20120121-4039-co662r-0 -jar start.jar
ubuntu   23125  0.0  0.0   7628  1004 pts/1    S+   10:47   0:00 grep --color=auto java

And my sunspot.yml file:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING

auto_commit_after_request: false
```

Sorry for the poor english, hope that someone could help me.

---

I still don't know what to do to correct this problem, the point is that I have only one model that is updated(not the indexed fields on searchable) all the time and solr just fail for this model, and not for the others.
Any help ?

Comment: Have you tried accessing solr with CURL? Paste the output of "ps aux | grep java" and your sunspot.yml file

Comment: I am not a Sunspot user but does the `Connection Refused` return any error code (400, 404, 500)? And could you include a sample URL generated by your Sunspot query?

Comment: Looks like the only Java process running in there is Jenkings, there is no Solr instance running in there.

Comment: It looks from `-Djetty.port=8983` that your Solr instance is started for a production environment. Can you `curl http://localhost:8983/solr` and get a response back? If you open an application console, what is the value for `Sunspot.config.solr.url`?

(Also, for what it's worth, the latest Sunspot code is at http://github.com/sunspot/sunspot. Probably not relevant to this problem.)

Comment: When curl localhost:8983/solr I didn't get any return, and Sunspot.config.solr.url returns: "localhost:8982/solr";. The strange thing is that my sunspot solr is up and running for all other models. What shoould I do ?

Comment: I still don't know what to do to correct this problem, the point is that I have only one model that is updated(not the indexed fields on searchable) all the time and solr just fail for this model, and not for the others. Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed a similar error before. It may be related if your error symptoms match:

The kind of error messages I have encountered is like this:

> Connection refused - connect(2)

with the backtrace:

```
/home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
...
rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
rsolr (1.0.8) lib/rsolr/connection.rb:15:in `execute'
```

Once I restarted sunspot solr server, errors will stop. During this time I can read indexes but not write to them.

---

**Solution**

The reason behind my error is that: I manually called `RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:start` on the production server, and I also use capistrano to deploy so it has the `current` directory and the shared directory.

When I run that start command in the `current` directory, for some reason the index file is still referenced by the release path (e.g. `release/2012xxxxxxxx/...`). Capistrano will delete old releases, so every now and then solr will not be able to reference the folder if it gets deleted.

The solution is to explicitly specify the index file path with the symlinked `current` directory:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:start --port=8983 --data-directory=#{current_path}/solr/data/#{rails_env} --pid-dir=#{current_path}/solr/pids/#{rails_env}"
```

Comment: --port is not a valid parameter to rake